# Push notifications through webview of a website?

Tags: android, webview

I created a webview on Android to display my website in the app. Now i want to know if it's possible to create notifications whenever i update the site content?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use cloud messaging service .. you have to implement it your server side in such a way that it would give a push to device whenever required

there are multiple option available most used are :-

Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
Parse: https://www.parse.com/